# auto tab with exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I primarily input single digit numbers. I want to auto tab to each input field, however, sometimes, there is a need for a two digit number. The two digit number will always start with "1". So I would like to auto tab on all single digit numbers except 1 and if a 1 is entered the auto tab is disabled so that a second digit can be entered. I will manually tab to the next field where auto tab would then resume.

I can find plenty of code for auto tabbing but none with this type of exception. I am new to javascript.

Comment: What have you tried? If you post your current tab code, it would be much easier to tell you how to modify it.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? Someone could easily think your form is broken or poorly programmed when they type `1` (only one) and autotab stops working. I'd rather have a form that functions consistently than one that saves me a minuscule amount of work sometimes.

Comment: Flimzy, I'm looking for code to try and will post if I can find something close to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: James, I'm not sure how else to do this. It appears that auto tab is triggered on maxlength. I could do some type of validation if a 1 is entered. With that said however, users will be aware that auto tab will stop on 1, so it will not be a surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/eH4K7/ (tested Chrome only)

However you'll need to do a lot more checks on the user input to get your desired effect.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. I can work with that. Thanks Brandon!